# Recursive Towers of Hanoi variation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I'm implementing a recursive solution of a variation to the classic Hanoi Towers problem where you can only move disks between neighbour pegs in order to solve it. My approximation is something like this:

> ```
> def hanoi_variation(n_disks, peg_1=1, peg_2=2, peg_3=3):
>     if n_disks == 1:
>          print('Move {} from peg {} to {}'.format(n_disks, peg_1, peg_2))
>          print('Move {} from peg {} to {}'.format(n_disks, peg_2, peg_3))
>
>     else:
>         hanoi_variation(n_disks - 1)
>         print('Move {} from peg {} to {}'.format(n_disks, peg_1, peg_2))
>         print('Move {} from peg {} to {}'.format(n_disks-1, peg_3, peg_2))
>         print('Move {} from peg {} to {}'.format(n_disks-1, peg_2, peg_1))
> ```

I understand that it needs to be a sequence where the smallest disk moves two times first to the right, then the second one moves one time and the first returns to the left with to movements... But for this implementation it only works at the first iteration. ¿Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: the expected output for 2 initial discs (which I consider is the base case) has to be:

> ```
> Move 1 from peg 1 to 2 
> Move 1 from peg 2 to 3 
> Move 2 from peg 1 to 2 
> Move 1 from peg 3 to 2 
> Move 1 from peg 2 to 1 
> Move 2 from peg 2 to 3 
> Move 1 from peg 1 to 2 
> Move 1 from peg 2 to 3
> ```

And what I get is:

> ```
> Move 1 from peg 1 to 2
> Move 1 from peg 2 to 3
> Move 2 from peg 1 to 2
> Move 1 from peg 3 to 2
> Move 1 from peg 2 to 1
> ```

Comment: Can you give the expected, complete output when the initial left tower has 4 discs?

Comment: @trincot I edited the question adding the 2-discs case (because with 4 would be much longer).

Comment: Thanks, but I would really want to see you doing that with 4 discs, as it seems impossible to do. Also, in your example with just 2 discs, I don't understand why that last move is done? Wasn't the target already achieved before that move?

Comment: Why, in the `else` branch, would the defaults for the pegs always be right? Why, with ode call to the 2-print base case and three more prints, would you expect eight?

Comment: @greybeard that's my problem, I don't know how to add functionality to the algorithm in order to move to the left

Comment: (That should have read *with one call* in my previous comment.) To add "functionality", you usually add code - more "naked" code, more calls, more (explicit) parameters, whatever. The usual recursive formulation for ToH moving n disks from a to c is move n-1 to b, 1 to c, and again n-1 from b to c. The latter, of course, consisting of n-2 to a, 1 to c, and n-2 from a to c. You will note that you have to move that single disk past the smaller tower somehow - not possible for your restriction for more than two disks. Try *four* pegs in quadrilateral arrangement. (Tetragonal? English, please…)

Comment: @trincot: I did second [you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67036606/recursive-towers-of-hanoi-variation-in-python/67050720#comment118496036_67036606), but, then…

Answer (score 0):

The universe is going to look at a much longer life with this restriction:

```
p  a
e  bbb  aa          aa
g  ccccccccc  aa  bbbbbb  aa          aa
1  ddddddddddddddddddddddddddd  aa  bbbbbb
p                                          a
e               a                 a     a bb
g      a     a bbb a     a     a bbb a ccccc
2   a bbb a ccccccccc a bbb a dddddddddddddd
p
e                            aa
g          aa          aa  bbbbbb  aa
3    aa  bbbbbb  aa  cccccccccccccccccc  aa
```

Non-recursive procedure:
There is no choice in the first move.
Out of the two moves possible thereafter, choose the one not undoing the previous one.

Recursive procedure:

```
"""
Towers of Hanoi.
Moves restricted to neighbouring peg
implement pegs begin, mid, end and procedure move() to meet your needs
"""
# loads of empty lines for spoiling



























def towers_of__H_a_n_o_i(d, source=begin, destination=end, other=mid):
    """
    Towers of Hanoi.
    Moves restricted to neighbouring peg
    """
    if d < 1: return  
    if mid == other:
        towers_of__H_a_n_o_i(d-1, source, destination)
        move(source, other)
        towers_of__H_a_n_o_i(d-1, destination, source)
        move(other, destination)
        towers_of__H_a_n_o_i(d-1, source, destination)
    else:
        towers_of__H_a_n_o_i(d-1, source, other, destination)
        move(source, destination)
        towers_of__H_a_n_o_i(d-1, other, destination, source)
```

Comment: I'm aware of [The Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#introduction).

Comment: The mid==other branch looks weird.